# Can we use Litz multi-strand wire as Tesla coil secondary?

Tags: transformer, circuit-design, electricity, tesla-coil, winding

I am making a mini Tesla coil as a proof of concept. I was thinking, can we use multiple enameled copper wires as the secondary? (Edit: Every wire is individually enameled and the ends  sanded to expose the copper, then soldered. The resulting "wire" is not flat, the individual wires are intertwined.)
After soldering the ends, if I use, say 10 wires, then if I wrap it 100 times, I'll end up with "**1000 turns**". Will this work?
Assuming both scenarios, where **wires are parallel** and where the **wires are jumbled**. I need a detailed answer, **Thanks** in advance.[image]

Comment: why do you believe that multi-strand wire uses insulated strands?

Comment: All the wires will effectively be in parallel you will not have 1000 turns you will still only have a hundred. What you are describing is similar to litz wire which does reduce high frequency losses but typically the diameter of wire used on a Tesla coil is thin enough that the skin effect is minimal.

Comment: A multi strand wire, for your concept is the same as a single strand wire. No detailed answer needed. Think about it.

Comment: @jsotola I have an inductor which has multi-strand enameled copper wire.

Comment: @Andy aka it's not the same, as mentioned by MadHatter, it is similar to litz wire. My guess is it can be considered multiple-core tesla coil.

Comment: @MadHatter by non-parallel I meant that the wires do not lie flat and overlap each other. I have read that any overlaps can cause problems.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you but, you do need to re-read what @madhatter says because he's right and, believe it or not, so am I.

Comment: @Andy aka our community is very supportive, and I know it. The thing is I tried to search for the use of multi-strand enameled wire in Tesla coils, and I failed to find anything at all (maybe due to my inexperience). So, I decided to ask you guys. I want a detailed answer viz. The effects of multiple insulated-wires on various properties of the Tesla coil. Also, I am unable to understand (again, due to my inexperience) how can seperate insulated wires be considered single wire. Won't they have their respective fields and maybe interference? Please help me out, I would love to learn from you.

Comment: Multi-strand wire, all along its length has all the strands shorting to each other in millions of places therefore it behaves like a single wire. I don't know how to explain this more simply. Because of induction (something you might not comprehend) and the careful way litz wire is made, despite all the strands being insulated, the voltage at the end of each strand is the same (then you solder them all together anyway).

Comment: @Anonymous Note that overlapping wires can have a tiny performance effect on a Tesla coil secondary, if the wires only overlap a bit in z due to sloppy winding realistically you're hardly going to even be able to see it with lab equipment measurements. The functionality of the coil will still be very similar to as if it was wound perfectly. I know this from experience... Before I had a coil winding machine, my hand wound coils would have some overlaps in places and measurements of similar coils to hand wound versus machine wound have turned up essentially identical Q, and res.

Comment: Thanks @MadHatter now i get it. Let me show you a piece of my wire.

Comment: @Andy aka, as i have mentioned before, the multiple wires can not short, because they are individually enameled. There is no contact between them except for their ends. Let me show you a piece of my wire.

Comment: @Anonymous you really have to learn to read the full comment.

Comment: I m sorry @Andy aka, I m from Biology background and electronics is new for me, so i don't understand things well enough. But i m sure with the support of guys like you, I'll be able to become much better at it. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @Andy aka can you help me please. Can u suggest me some reading material so that i can get my basics clear?

Comment: I know a lot about this subject and therefore I haven't used reading material to help me learn it in at least 30 years.

Comment: @Andy aka, wow that's a lot of experience. I'll ask for ur help, if u don't mind, in the future.

Comment: I would honestly suggest you watch them YouTube about Tesla coils, or find a easy looking do it yourself guide, there are a lot of guides of people building Tesla coils online... Also for a small one look up Slayer Exciter circuits...

Comment: Thanks @MadHatter I'll definitely do that. I did try to look for Litz wire tesla coils, and nothing promising came up. I also tried searching for multi-core tesla coil. Now, I'll do as u said. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the individual wires will effectively be in parallel. You will not have 1000 turns, you will still only have 100 turns. What you are describing is similar to litz wire which does reduce high frequency losses but typically the diameter of wire used on a Tesla coil is thin enough that the skin effect is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Litz wire has the advantage of remedying the skin effect... At higher frequencies only a thin surface of a wire conducts. More insulated wires means more conduction .  I've built Tesla coil secondaries with litz and had it work very well.